# isotope multi level filtering not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

i'm trying to create a filterable course list using isotope, but my filters don't seem to work with each other. i'm using the same js as the example provided on isotope's site, my pen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbMVqp

ex. selecting "college of arts & history" and "b.a." will list programs from other colleges. i need to only show b.a. programs in college of arts & history. is this working as intended or will I need to add some sort of logic?

js

```
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.courses').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid__item',
    layoutMode: 'vertical',

});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$('.filters').on( 'change', function( event ) {
  var $select = $( event.target );
  // get group key
  var filterGroup = $select.attr('value-group');
  // set filter for group
  filters[ filterGroup ] = event.target.value;
  // combine filters
  var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
  // set filter for Isotope
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured I was missing the `value-group` attribute in my html.